# 4mA to 20mA transmitter design question

Tags: circuit-analysis

Checking [Vishay AN54](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83710/appn54.pdf) using IL300 for current loops, the Figure 6 (Isolated 1 V to 5 V, 4 mA to 20 mA Transmitter) circuit is explained but I really don´t get exactly how it works.

[image: Isolated 1 V to 5 V, 4 mA to 20 mA Transmitter]

Other interesting document on this IL300 device is [here](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83708/appnote50.pdf), where multiple circuit topologies are explained (included the one similar to the figure, in fig.15, page 8).

I have imported this design to LTSpice to check how it works.
After checking the simulation this is how I think it works (please correct me here if any of these points is not correct):

1.- K1 = K2 so IP1 = IP2.

2.- To set IP1 just take Vin and R1. IP1=Vin/R1

3.- As IP1 = IP2, current through R3 is equal to current through R1, IR3 = IR1.

4.- Due to negative feedback in U2, VR3 = VR4, so loop current can be configured changing the value of R4. Iloop = IR4

5.- 100pF capacitor is placed in order to avoid voltage ripple.

6.- Transistor is placed to reduce thermal drift of U1.

So, main operation of the whole circuit is more or less understood.

The main question comes when, checking the current at the output of U1, this current is exactly the same as the one through R1.

**UPDATE**

Please check the simulation and the analysis of the current in both U1 output and R1 output:

[image]

Please keep in mind current sign just depends on how it is being measured...if the current is measured at the base of the transistor, both R1 and U1 output current are exactly the same.

Can anyone help me here to explain how the current in R1 is being replicated at the output of U1? I still don´t get it.

Comment: What do you mean with "exactly"? The current on U1 output is amplified by the transistor, beta is around 100 for that model. K1 is then about 1/100, so those cancel out, so you may have a current that approximately looks like what is flowing in R1. Is this the case, perhaps?

Comment: The output current of U1 is the current that flows from U1 output, not the transistor output.

Comment: Hope the figure of the simulation added to the update helps understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit goal is to have a good replica of the input current, from Vin-R1, flow through IP2. The replica is then amplified and sent to the next device in the chain.

To have a good replica of the current, you need to shine light on IP2 through the LED inside the IL300, but of course you need to shine just the right amount of light. To do so, you should know K2 down to a very high precision, but unfortunately in microelectronics having a value be very near something is difficult. What we are good at doing is matching values, so the manufacturer guarantees that K1 and K2 are very well matched, but their absolute value can vary quite a lot.

So you know that to have a replica in IP2, you should shine on it the same light that produces a good replica on IP1, because K1 = K2.

You achieve this by having the input current flowing into IP1, and then having a negative feedback ckt that feeds the diode with just the right amount of current in order to have the right current flowing into IP1.

How does this happen? Assume that Vin goes up a tiny bit, then the voltage on the inverting input of U1 goes up the same tiny bit, because IP1 cannot change since the light has not changed.

The opamp now sees a more negative voltage, thus it absorbs more current. That current is amplified by the transistor, and more current flows into the LED. More current in the LED means more light means more current in IP1 means more drop in R1 means that the negative input goes back to zero, and the opamp is happy and doing its job.

The output current of the opamp is thus very similar to the input current, because the circuit is built in the way it is built. The gain of the transistor is ~100, while the gain of the optocoupler is ~1/100, so this can lead you to think that the two currents are the same. They are not, they are incidentally very similar in amplitude, but if you change the K1 of the model of the IL300, you will see that the current will change in amplitude.

The shape of the currents are very similar because the transistor that amplifies, and the IL300, are pretty linear. If you had non linearities, you would see a very different current, just the right current to compensate for all the ckt non linearities.

Comment: Doesn´t IP1 depend on Vin/R1? If Vin changes IP1 will also change as it is Vin/R1. So, from what you´re saying the op amp negative input will be able to modify its voltage instead of sinking the current variation to the IP1 branch. Regarding the current at the op amp, yes, I´ve already tried another transistor and, while still having IP1 constant, the op amp output shows a different current...

Comment: IP1 does not depend on Vin/R1, IP1 depends on the light that hits it. The fact that at the end of the day IP1 = Vin/R1 is true because the opamp is modulating the light hitting the detector. Try connecting pin 1 of IL300 to ground. What happens? @user6127833

Comment: Connecting pin 1 to GND and measuring current in pin 4 IO find the current in that brach varies from 130uA to 148uA. If your statemet is correct, it should be 0, right?

Comment: No. Disabling the light source as you can see the current in IP1 no longer is V/R, but much less, and there also is a different average than before. This can be from a model limit, or leakage, or something else I cannot imagine right now. As I have said, the current in the IP1 side is set by the light, and the circuit on the left side is built so that the light sets the current equal to V/R, so IP1 depends on light, light depends on V/R, this is the most accurate chain.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation